# can i use listener in listener

Tags: android, listener

i am now develop an app,when it comes to register progress, i need to set a listener in a register button to send the information to the server,at the same time, i want to set a listener in a sex choice button which is used RadioGroup.when i set the listener which is for radiogroup in a listener for regist,it seems the radiogroup listener did not work properly.i am wonder why.here is the code

```
findViewById(R.id.rigister_btn_register).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            EditText accountEt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_account);
            EditText passwordEt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
            EditText nickEt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_nick);

            /*RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.register_radiogroup);
            RadioButton maleButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.register_radio_nan);
            maleButton.setChecked(true);

            group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,int id) {

            RadioButton femaleButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.register_radio_nv);
                    if(id==femaleButton.getId()){
                        sex="female";

                    }
                }
            });*/
```

btw,the var "sex" has been  initialized at the beginning of the class which is male.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with setting a listener inside of a listener. I'm not sure if that's what you want to do though-  wouldn't it make more sense just to always have both listeners on?  Or since this seems to be a form-  just to check which option is picked when the user hits the submit button?

Comment: first,thanks for commenting on my question.i have tried to set two listeners apart,which works.since you said that there is nothing wrong, i would try to debug it to find the bug.